Adding Swift Package Dependencies in Xcode Blank Template Playgrounds
I'm using the Xcode Blank Template Playground because it’s very lightweight for testing some code. However, I encountered an issue when trying to add Swift package dependencies—the button is greyed out. For context, I am using Xcode Playground as a standalone "file," not within a project.
I also tried adding my custom package dependencies in a blank project, which was successful. Unfortunately, when I created a Playground within that project, I was still unable to import my library. Everything works fine when creating a Swift file, but it seems that inside a Playground, it does not work.
I also checked this video and is not what I needed: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10096

So here is a picture working perfectly fine inside a Swift file (Blank Project)

and here is with a playground (I usually do not use playgrounds in Projects but it was the only way to successfully add a library).

Is there a way to add package dependencies in a lightweight environment like Xcode Playgrounds? I need individual small script/testing files, which is why I use Xcode Playgrounds.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

It took me some time to figure it out. If you need to share sources, you can use Xcode Playground. If you need to add modules to your Playground, like I did, you can use Swift Playgrounds (App) with a .playgroundbook file, which can be found right here. However, this was not ideal for me because my library required a terminal.

So in my case, a Command Line Tool is perfect. You can select from Swift, Objective-C, C++, or C. It also has a terminal and is lightweight, and you can add package dependencies.

